# Some sub domains taking time to load

Tags: php, mysql, apache, response

I have some subdomain sites in my server which sometimes quickly load in browser but sometimes it takes lot of time to load the main page of those subdomains.
But when I restart my Apache web server and MySQL server  those start running fast but after some minutes those subdomains again take time to load.where as my home page is always fast.
Some subdomains are WordPress sites and some are static subdomains.static ones load fast always.
Problem is with WordPress subdomains.i Don't know why it takes time to load after some minutes of server and machine restart

Comment: what is the best response time and what is the load and memory usage when subdomain are slow ?

Comment: This is really broad, and could be caused due to any number of reasons.

Comment: @Mohd alomar-best response Time in the sense that those sub domains are to be loaded in max 2 seconds but sometimes it takes more than 10 seconds.i will let u Know for memory usage

Comment: @Adam, how can I search reasons.any guidance on that

Comment: @Adam is absolutely right.  What does your `vhost/conf` file look like?  What about any rewrite rules in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: @mtr.web ,in htaccess file rule is only for main domain to redirect it to www.domain.com from domain.com and there are some caching rules added.in httpd.conf file there are vurtualhost configured for Mass sub folders to make it aubdomains in the form of virtualdocument root.but why only WordPress subdomain are impacted with performance that point is very trivial.